# crossthreading cross class vb.net issue

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, function

i have my form class, and a second module with some special functions,
when i click a button on my form i run a public function from the second module(which run later other public functions from the second module) in a separated thread, i set SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA), and i tried using deletage sub and CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False, but the problem stays the same, my thread functions (which are on the second module) can't access my form controls, but when i move the functions to the form class everything work again, what do you suggest to solve this issue?

```
Public Class Form1
Dim T0 As Thread

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    T0 = New Thread(AddressOf sub1)
    T0.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    T0.start()
End Sub
End Class


Module Module1

Public Sub Sub1()
msgbox(form1.textbox1.text)    'even if the textbox contains content it returns ""    
Function2()
End Sub

Public Function Function1()
'SomeInstructions
msgbox(form1.textbox1.text)    'same problem here
End Function

End module
```

PS: it dosn't give any error or stop the code while debugging, and i tried to put the sub1 on the form class and the other functions in the module, but then,  only he sub1 can access the controls, i tried delegate but i don't know if i have done it right, can anyone make any suggestions please

Comment: Please include a minimal example which would demonstrate the described behaviour. I have no doubt that the solution is trivial, but without seeing some code it's hard to tell where the problem is.

Comment: I juste did if anyone can suggest how to solve this please

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues at play here.

One of them is due to the way default forms work in VB.NET. See, in C# you need a concrete instance of type `Form1` in order to access its non-static members, whereas in VB.NET `Form1` *looks* like an instance of the form allowing you to write things like `Form1.TextBox1.Text`. This works fine while you're accessing members of `Form1` from the UI thread, but when you try to get it from a background thread, a *new* instance of `Form1` is created, and `Form1.TextBox1` seen by that thread actually points to a completely different instance of `TextBox`.

Another way saying this is that default form instances in VB.NET are *thread static*.

A way to get around this is to keep a concrete reference to `Form1` so that you can pass it around.

When you go

```
Dim myForm As New Form1
```

... or

```
Dim myForm As Form1 = Me
```

... the 'myForm' variable pointing to that specific `Form1` instance can then be passed between threads like any other reference and will not change its meaning.

This, however, brings us to issue #2:

**You should not be accessing a UI control (which means any type derived from** `Control`**, and that includes** `Form` **, from a thread other than the thread that it was created on.**

If you absolutely have to, you have to marshal the calls accessing the `Control` to the thread that it was created on, for example by using `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` (there are other ways too).

Here's a modification of your code to achieve what you want, plus a more complex example which demonstrates multiple thread "switches": gathering interesting state on the UI thread, performing work with it on the background thread, then displaying results on the UI thread.

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' We don't need this anymore.
    ' We'll do things right and access
    ' the UI on the UI thread only.
    ' CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Note that we're passing a reference
    ' to THIS instance of Form1 to Sub1 and Sub2.
    Dim form As Form1 = Me

    ' Let's spin up some threads.
    Dim T0 As New Thread(Sub() Module1.Sub1(form))

    T0.Start()

    Dim T1 As New Thread(Sub() Module1.Sub2(form))

    T1.Start()
  End Sub

End Class

Module Module1

  ' Note that this sub now accepts
  ' a reference to an instance of Form1.
  Public Sub Sub1(form As Form1)
    ' This is what we want to do:
    Dim action As New Action(Sub() MsgBox(form.TextBox1.Text))

    ' See if we're on the right thread.
    If form.InvokeRequired Then
      ' Invoke on the thread which created this Form1 instance.
      form.Invoke(action)
    Else
      ' Invoke on the current thread.
      action.Invoke()
    End If
  End Sub

  ' This is a more complex example.
  Public Sub Sub2(form As Form1)
    ' This function will get the text from TextBox1 when invoked.
    ' It still needs to be invoked on the UI thread though.
    Dim getText As New Func(Of String)(Function() form.TextBox1.Text)

    Dim text As String

    If form.InvokeRequired Then
      text = CStr(form.Invoke(getText))
    Else
      text = getText() ' Shorthand syntax.
    End If

    ' Now that we have the text, let's do some
    ' intensive work with it while we're on
    ' the background thread.
    For i = 0 To 5
      text &= i

      Thread.Sleep(100)
    Next

    ' Now we want to show the message box - again, on the UI thread.
    Dim showMessageBox As New Action(Sub() MsgBox(text))

    If form.InvokeRequired Then
      form.Invoke(showMessageBox)
    Else
      showMessageBox()
    End If
  End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you, as i'm pretty new to vb.net i didn't get the code you wrote, but using the form variable was helpfull

Comment: @user3781458, if the code above looks like gibberish to you it's because **a)** it relies on low-level constructs from the days where async programming was a form of art; there are better tools available in modern VB.NET, namely `Task` and Async/Await; and **b)** it requires an understanding of *delegates* and *closures*, which is indispensable for writing quality async code (and useful for working with certain other technologies, such as LINQ).